# Odoo: error 98 Adress already in use, how to fix?

Tags: docker, odoo, odoo-15

Odoo 15, installed on ubuntu server **in docker container**

i didnt installed it myself, admin tell me that he cant solve this problem

```
site1@site1:/var/docker/odoo$ docker exec -it odoo bash
odoo@f6740a7479b8:/$ odoo
2022-07-22 20:23:53,743 59 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 15.0-20220620
2022-07-22 20:23:53,743 59 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf
2022-07-22 20:23:53,743 59 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons', '/var/lib/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/15.0', '/var/odoo/custom']
2022-07-22 20:23:53,743 59 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@db:5432
2022-07-22 20:23:53,914 59 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
2022-07-22 20:23:54,150 59 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/odoo", line 8, in <module>
    odoo.cli.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/cli/command.py", line 61, in main
    o.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/cli/server.py", line 179, in run
    main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/cli/server.py", line 173, in main
    rc = odoo.service.server.start(preload=preload, stop=stop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 1356, in start
    rc = server.run(preload, stop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 907, in run
    self.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 877, in start
    self.socket.bind((self.interface, self.port))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

when i trying to update module or just execute odoo for outputs, this error occured.
but instad, odoo worked, i can develop and update modules manualy from browser.

i tried next solutions:

1. adding `xmlrpc_port = 7654` to config file
   didnt work, error also occured and odoo web intarface isnt available.
2. changing ports in docker compose file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  web:
    build: ./etc/odoo    
    container_name: odoo
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
```

in all variations, didnt help. How to solve that problem?

Comment: Your container probably already started odoo and you are trying to start it second time

Comment: @Paxmees, i just realize this. Maybe you can help me with one question. Sometimes i need to run "odoo" comand with some parameters like "odoo --update mymodule". If i use odoo in my pc, i can do this, but in docker container odoo is started already and error occures. Is it possible to do something with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container probably already started odoo and you are trying to start it second time.

To execute commands in container you can try `--no-http` parameter

Comment: i am geting`Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?`
when i try to do the same